# cudaMemcpyAsync with pageable memory blocks host thread?

Tags: cuda

I wrote a simple code about cudaMemcpyAsync with pageable memroy and did some profiling.

**Kernel**

```
__global__ void
vectorScale(float *C, float scal, size_t numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    clock_t start_clock = clock();
    clock_t clock_offset = 0;
    while (clock_offset < 14100){
        clock_offset = clock() - start_clock;
    }

    if (i < numElements) C[i] *= scal;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cudaStream_t stream;
    // Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size
    size_t numElements = 1024*1024*256;
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
    printf("[Vector scale of %zu elements]\n", numElements);

    float *h_C; 
    if(argc==1) h_C = (float *)malloc(size);
    else cudaHostAlloc((void**)&h_C, size, cudaHostAllocPortable);

    // Initialize the host input vectors
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
        h_C[i] = i*0.01;

    // Allocate the device vector C
    float *d_C = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_C, h_C, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);

    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    vectorScale<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, 0, stream>>>(d_C, 2.0, numElements);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

    // Free device global memory
    cudaFree(d_C);

    // Free host memory
    if(argc==1) free(h_C);
    else cudaFreeHost(h_C);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);

    return 0;
}
```

**Profiling**
[image]

As the snapshot shown, in row "CUDA API", the time cost of cudaMemcpyAsync is big, which means the host thead is blocked. It looks inconsistent with the document guide.

BTW, if I use pinned memory, cudaMemcpyAsync behave as expected, the host thread blocks at the cudaStreamSynchronize().

Comment: The documentation says "This function exhibits asynchronous behavior for most use cases." . I don't see how that is inconsistent with anything in your question

Comment: asynchronous behavior means host thread call the api cudaMemcpyAsync and go to the next cpu code at once,  the time cost  of api call should be negligible. My profiling result show that the api call cost the same time as memcpy.

Comment: Did you read all the words in that sentence I quoted from the documentation? I will try again: "*This function exhibits asynchronous behavior for **most** use cases.*" Note: "most", not "all"

Answer (score 1):

It seems evident (your test case is a proof point) that in some circumstances `cudaMemcpyAsync` may become a blocking operation for the host thread, no longer being "asynchronous" with respect to other host CPU thread activity.

I don't find any evidence that this is contradicted by the documentation, which doesn't have any statements like "under no circumstances will `cudaMemcpyAsync` block the host thread".  If you know of any such statements, please point them out.  In fact, [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-execution-host-device) indicates that what you are observing is expected:

> Async memory copies will also be synchronous if they involve host memory that is not page-locked.

The asynchronous character of `cudaMemcpyAsync` depends on transferring data to or from a pinned allocation (for the transfer directions of D->H or H->D).  The pinned allocation is required so that the underlying operation programmed into the DMA engine that would do the transfer "asynchronously" has a fixed mapping for the host data.  This is required.

A pageable allocation means that the underlying logical->physical mapping can change at any time, which prevents ordinary operation of `cudaMemcpyAsync`.  Since the intended use case for `cudaMemcpyAsync` is to copy data to/from a pinned allocation, I surmise that the CUDA runtime API developers feel that acceptable behavior in this situation is to block the host thread and complete the transfer "immediately" (i.e. synchronously.  I would not expect any violation of CUDA stream semantics for the transfer, whether synchronous or asynchronous).  Again, your test case is a proof point.

The only other alternative to continue to provide "asynchronous" behavior w.r.t. the host thread that I can imagine would be to spin up another CPU thread to handle the operation asynchronously.  Again, I surmise that the CUDA runtime API developers feel that development and maintenance of such machinery is unwarranted for the non-preferred use case of this API.

However the conjecture here is beside the point; I don't wish to argue it.  The main idea is that what you are observing is expected behavior.